# Bypassing anti-debugging

Tags: anti-debugging

I'm trying to RE Stardew Valley to write cheats for it. The problem is that when I trace the pointers for my health/energy/etc... back more than one level the game crashes. It probably has some kind of anti-debugging checks in it. I looked into it a little bit and apparently there's a bunch of things they can do to detect debuggers and exit - does anyone know of a good way to figure out what they're doing without just searching the binary in IDA? I could do that but it seems like a bit of a pain in the arse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which debugger you are using, there are a few options.

VEH debugger option in Cheat Engine will bypass some anti-debugging techniques.

If you use x64dbg or x32dbg, you can use ScyllaHide:
https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide

There is also TitanHide(kernel mode):
https://github.com/mrexodia/TitanHide